# Makita RT0700C plunge base, is the plastic guard detachable?

Tags: router, power-tools

[image]

I didn't find anything on this in the user manual. If this is similar to my previous router (Bosch branded), you would think that it simply rotates when you need a clear view of the router bit.
I tried to detach it by pulling (gently) on the top, so that it rotates along what I think are hinges on the bottom, but it's really stiff, judging from the high pitch sound it's making when it snaps back. If I pull harder, I know it's going to either rotate, or break, and I'm not taking any chances.

Comment: IMHO, from that picture, it's very hard to tell. It looks like there may be a clip toward the left edge that locks it in place, but from this side of the screen, it's hard to be certain.

Comment: @FreeMan, for what little it's worth that's how that reads to me too.

Comment: If this is a push-in/pull-out part, held in place by a clip in a detent or acting against a raised lip it could be that this was designed not to be easy to remove. In which case working with it in place may be your only option, can you think of ways you might work around it? There's no guard on the other side for example....

Comment: I have found how to detach it. I'm going to take a few pictures and self answer. Documentation was  defective w.r.t the guard..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a compliant mechanism. You have to squeeze it slightly like this
[image]
[image]

in order to slide it up:
[image]

The two V-blocks at the back are supports for the rails of the parallel guide.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Be sure to click the checkmark, too so others will know it's resolved.